# How to install Padre on ActivePerl 5.16.2?

Tags: perl, padre

I need to  install Padre on ActivePerl 5.16.2. But there are no Padre ppm packages and 
cpan Padre says:

```
  MDOOTSON/Alien-wxWidgets-0.64.tar.gz
  C:\Perl\site\bin\dmake.exe -- NOT OK
  CPAN: YAML::XS loaded ok (v0.38)
  Running make test
    Can't test without successful make
  Running make install
    Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
  Running make for P/PL/PLAVEN/Padre-0.98.tar.gz
  Warning: Prerequisite 'Alien::wxWidgets => 0.62' for 'PLAVEN/Padre-0.98.tar.gz'                                                  failed when processing 'MDOOTSON/Alien-wxWidgets-0.64.tar
  CPAN: Time::HiRes loaded ok (v1.9725)

    CPAN.pm: Building P/PL/PLAVEN/Padre-0.98.tar.gz

  Set up gcc environment - 3.4.5 (mingw-vista special r3)
  Can't locate Alien/wxWidgets.pm in @INC (@INC contains: inc privinc C:\Perl\dbg                     C:/Perl/site/lib C:/Perl/lib .) at Makefile.PL line 52.
  BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Makefile.PL line 52.
  Warning: No success on command[C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site]
    PLAVEN/Padre-0.98.tar.gz
    C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site -- NOT OK
  Running make test
    Make had some problems, won't test
  Running make install
    Make had some problems, won't install
  Could not read metadata file. Falling back to other methods to determine prerequisites
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr Padre for ActivePerl 5.16 has not been released yet.

The following contents are just me trying to make it work.

First I tried:

```
cpan Padre
```

I did this three times, but "dmake.exe" always failed.
There was no reference about this error on the Internet.

Secondly I tried PPM with [an article in Padre Wiki](http://padre.perlide.org/trac/wiki/DownloadActivePerl):

```
ppm rep add wxperl http://www.wxperl.co.uk/repository

ppm install Alien-wxWidgets
ppm install Wx
ppm install Padre
```

but the very last line claimed:

```
ppm install failed: Can't find any package that provides Padre
```

Finally I couldn't help talking to the Padre developers:

[image]

So, apparently we have nothing to do but wait for them to develop it.
Or you can participate to the development, of course!

Answer (score 0):

This post should help: [Installation instructions for Wx (wxWidgets fomerly wxWindows) using ActivePerl](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=813799)